# Copy command Not working in DevCenter

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have DevCenter 1.2.1.Some CQL commands working well but **COPY** command is not working.It shows error message "You made a type...sorry typo".Any hint???

Comment: can you define the error message properly?
copy paste your error message.

Comment: This is actual error.There is one syntax error in the current script (see details below).
Please fix it and try again.
  Line 1: Invalid tokens: COPY, airplanes, (, name, ,, manufacturer, ,, year, ,, mach, ), FROM, 'temp.csv'

Comment: is this your query?
 COPY, airplanes, (, name, ,, manufacturer, ,, year, ,, mach, ), FROM, 'temp.csv' ???

Comment: This is query-"COPY airplanes (name, manufacturer, year, mach) FROM 'temp.csv';".when I run this query it shows above error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The copy command, as well as [some other commands](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCommandsTOC.html) are unique to cqlsh only and not part of the CQL spec proper, so they cannot be used in DevCenter.

Source: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/java-driver-user/JQXF99YAB_E (what applies to drivers also applies to DevCenter)

Comment: As an addition: you can enter `cqlsh` and then type `help`. You'll see "_Documented shell commands:_" that are available only from _cqlsh_. Those are: CAPTURE, COPY, DESCRIBE, EXPAND, PAGING, SOURCE, CONSISTENCY, DESC, EXIT, HELP, SHOW, TRACING.

Answer (score 3):

While DevCenter does not support cqlsh specific commands such as COPY, it does allow you to copy results of a query from the Results view in either a CSV or INSERT statement format.

For CSV, execute your query and select the rows you want to copy in the Results view, then right-click and select "COPY as CSV". You can also select "COPY All as CSV" as a shortcut if you want all rows from the result set. This will copy all the result data to the clipboard and the format of this data should be compatible with cqlsh COPY. You can paste this data into a file to get a result similar to COPY TO in cqlsh.

You cannot directly achieve the same thing as cqlsh COPY FROM in DevCenter, however the "Copy [All] as INSERT" option provides the ability to generate INSERT statements from a given query result set to the clipboard which can then be pasted back into the editor and executed again. For small data sets, this method can be a convenient to create a script to load data for testing or backup.

Comment: DevCenter version 1.6.0 now has the ability to "Export All results to File as [CSV|Insert]" which allows all the results of a query to be exported.

Comment: I am using DevCenter v1.6.0  client tool to interact with my Cassandra Cluster.
Unfortunately most of the CQL commands dont work on this , most of the keywords of the query are not been recognized.

Ex: describe or desc

I am trying query exactly as mentioned in the document.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshDescribeKeyspace.html

Is there any extra setting/configuration I need to do to my DevCenter v1.6.0  client work with CQL commands?

Please help me.

Comment: "describe" is a CQL shell command, e.g. a command for the cqlsh program, rather than a CQL language statement. DevCenter does not recognize cqlsh specific commands such as those listed in the section called "CQL shell commands" in the link you provided. DevCenter has a Schema View that you can use to display and explore your schema. Final note: DataStax Studio replaces DevCenter and does support the "describe" command.